# Can't start an application as service, but running as standalone process simply works

Tags: 12.04, permissions, services, cassandra

For a service although a pid file exists, but still when attempting to start service, it fails saying:

```
$ sudo service cassandra start
* could not access pidfile for Cassandra
```

I verified folder permissions under `/var/run` (whose owner is root) and the subfolder cassandra is owned by cassandra user, but still the service cannot access pid file even though I verified that pid file exists. (Also pid is allocated). So why does it say it can't access pidfile?

And running `cassandra` as a standalone process just works, but not  just using `service cassandra start`

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/run/cassandra 
total 4 
-rw-r--r-- 1 cassandra cassandra 4 Mar 18 07:33 cassandra.pid
$ sudo su
# ls -ld /var/run/cassandra 
dr--r----- 2 cassandra cassandra 60 Mar 18 07:38 /var/run/cassandra
```

How do I make this work using `sudo service cassandra start` ?

Comment: How did you install Cassandra?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install cassandra dsc20`

Comment: Then just run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure cassandra`

Comment: tried this out.. but no effect still same error..

Comment: Then try to remove pid file and start cassandra.

Comment: it created a new pid file on start but same message on cheking status,, `* could not access pidfile for Cassandra`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13674/discussion-between-danatela-and-user01)

Comment: another thing of importance, I observed that the user that is supposd to run cassandra/access cassandra(/var/run) folder(ie, user created by cassandra package itself to run cassandra), I can't switch myself to that cassandra user.. using `sudo -iu cassandra`

Comment: it doesnot acutally switch me to that user,, hence  cassandra user does not get the permissions to access that `/var/run/cassandra` folder..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove `/var/run/cassandra` folder hence it has wrong permissions:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/run/cassandra
```

Or you can fix permissions manually:

```
sudo chmod 750 /var/run/cassandra
```

Then start Cassandra as service:

```
sudo service cassandra start
```

---

### Some explanations

Instructions of file permissions you can find [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions).

- It is safe to delete that folder because it recreates with right permissions and content. But do not delete it once it works correct. It may result in loss of data or incorrect behavior.
- `chmod 750` decrypts as rwxr-x--- permissions. It allows read-write-execute to the user, read-execute to the group and nothing to others. For Cassandra, it is enough to set permissions so.

Comment: is it safe to remove this folder ? does it get created as it was before ?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, if after deleting `/var/run/cassandra` if it works/ runs, does that mean it has not lost any data ?

Comment: Probably does. Sorry, I don't know the purpose of Cassandra. May be you will find info about this in it's manual.

Answer (score 2):

This solution can be achieved the following way:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/init.d/cassandra;
```

Find the following line:

```
CMD_PATT="cassandra.+CassandraDaemon"
```

Replace by:

```
CMD_PATT="cassandra"
```

Save and stop and start again. Service will get status correctly;
Tested on cassandra 2.3

Source here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-cassandra-and-run-a-single-node-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04
(check STEP 3)

Answer (score 0):

My solution for migration of Cassandra 2.0.9 to 2.1.4

After upgrade with

```
sudo apt-get install dsc21
```

Go to log file:

```
tail -f /var/log/cassandra/system.log
```

You can see you need to modify your cassandra configuration file.

1. Stop Cassandra

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/cassandra stop
   ```
2. Go to Cassandra configuration file

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
   ```
3. Comment out these 5 lines or remove them:

   - `multithreaded_compaction: false`
   - `preheat_kernel_page_cache: false`
   - `memtable_flush_queue_size: 4`
   - `in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb: 64`
   - `compaction_preheat_key_cache: true`
4. Start Cassandra

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/cassandra start
   ```
5. Verify

   ```
   nodetool status
   ```