# Is it safe to remove a process folder from /var/run/?

Tags: 12.04, services, process

Is it safe to remove a process folder from `/var/run/` if I think it has got wrong permissions, will it be recreated by process as before?

Do I lose any information by deleting `/var/run/<process folder>` when the process is not running?

After deleting if it works/runs, does that mean it has not lost any data?

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101), could you explain why you think this is necessary?

Comment: @terdon, look into his questions, the [previous one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/435749/cant-start-an-application-as-service-but-running-as-standalone-process-simply) was solved by removing folder from `/var/run`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the process. In most cases, a reboot should clear out the whole folder, but to be on the safe side, stop the process before deleting the folder.